# Is a function with two variables a invertible function?

Tags: functions

Is a function with two variables a invertible function?

for example $p(n,r) = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ is this function an invertible function?

Comment: Some are, some aren’t. Yours isn’t, since $p(n,r)=p(n,n-r)$.

Comment: a function is invertible if it is bijective(injective and surjective), this has nothing to do with the number of variables it has.

Comment: thanks for your help!

Comment: Also notice that Is fundamental to specify domain and codomain of the function. Because invertibility depends on that choice

Comment: A graphical representation helps. A function $f: (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \to z \in \mathbb{R}$ is represented in general by a surface. Being given $z_0$, the set of point $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=z_0$ is a "level set", the intersection with horizontal plan $z=z_0$ with the surface. In general, this level set is a curve and not a single point...

Comment: @FShrike You're thinking of the binomial coefficient. For OP's function, $p(5,3)=60$ but $p(5,5-3)=20.$

Comment: If you restrict the domain and range enough you can make any function invertible.

Comment: post it as a answer so I can mark it as correct..